# how to view database inside phone internal memory

Tags: android

im creating an application which save database inside phone application directory my question is  i know how to view database in eclipse but i want to view database in phone when application run how i will see database in phone???

```
             public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.myapp/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "YummiSlice.sqlite";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private SQLiteDatabase myData; 

private final Context myContext;

public DataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   
/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{  
        CopyFiles();
    }
}

private void CopyFiles()
{
    try
    { 
       InputStream is = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
       File outfile = new File(DB_PATH,DB_NAME);
       outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
       outfile.createNewFile();

      if (is == null)
      throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
      else
      {
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfile);      
          byte buf[] = new byte[128];
            do {
          int numread = is.read(buf);
                if (numread <= 0)
                    break;
          out.write(buf, 0, numread);
           } while (true);

            is.close();
            out.close();
      }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
          throw new RuntimeException(e); 
    }

}    

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the  
     application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

 public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
  String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

 }

 @Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


  //---retrieve records---
  public Cursor selectQuery(String query) throws SQLException 
  {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Cursor mCursor =myData.rawQuery(query, null);
    mCursor.moveToFirst();      
    myData.close();

    return mCursor;
 }


 ////////// For Insert And Update Data ////////
 public void insert_update(String query) throws SQLException 
 {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    myData.execSQL(query);
    myData.close();        
 }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, with a rooted phone or a emulator, you can use the DDMS tab to view SQLite database.

Go to file explorer -> data -> data -> package name -> database name

You can now push or pull the database...

On a non rooted phone, you have to use adb backup to realise a backup of your database.
exemple here : http://dbremes.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/how-to-get-a-backup-of-your-android-applications-database-in-windows/

Comment: how i will see database in runtime any application available?? i dont want to use eclipse